# create a Custom View and use it in storyboard

Tags: swift, uiview

I created a custom view that may be used in a storyboard or added Programmatically:

```
@IBDesignable
class PageView: UIView {
}
```

and override init method and call `commoninit()` to add a `imageview` as subview

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    commonInit()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    commonInit()
}

func commonInit(){
    print(self.bounds)
    let imgview = UIImageView(frame: self.bounds)
    imgview.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imgview.clipsToBounds = true
    imgview.backgroundColor = .red
    imgview.image = pageImage
    addSubview(imgview)
    bringSubview(toFront: imgview)
    self.pageImageView = imgview

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: imgview,attribute: .top,relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self,attribute: .top,multiplier: 1,constant: 0).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: imgview,attribute: .leading,relatedBy: .equal,toItem: self,attribute: .leading,multiplier: 1,constant: 0).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self,attribute: .bottom,relatedBy: .equal,toItem: imgview,attribute: .bottom,multiplier: 1,constant: 0).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self,attribute: .trailing,relatedBy: .equal,toItem: imgview,attribute: .trailing,multiplier: 1,constant: 0).isActive = true

    self.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()

    // add Gesture
    addGestureRecognizer(UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onLongPress(_:))))
}
```

After using it in storyboard, the `view.bound` is the size of the selected device size in storyboard, not the actual device I run on it. For simplicity, I design on `iPhone 8` size and run on `iphone 8 Plus`.

It looks like this:

[image]

and on simulator like this:

[image]

Why is the view size the design size and not the actual size? 
How to get the actual size of view ?

Comment: show me the actual code where you placing your customeView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using constraints should set translatesAutoresizingmaskintoconstraint property to false. try to put this code before adding as subview.

```
imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Comment: this work great when using constrains , but without the constrain the imgView size  still the same "not take full SuperView size"

Comment: check by removing imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false and constraint adding codes. and try to set frame of imageview like let imgview = UIImageView(frame: self.bounds.frame)

Comment: the frame for self.bounds.frame is not in the size of the device size ,  it still take the size from the sub view in the vc that is in xib/storyboard